# Is it possible to use Druidcraft and Control Weather to tell if a given event will succeed?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, druid, weather

Example: a Druid and his party decide to go get rid of an orc tribe. The weather is currently clear, with no precipitation. If the party succeeds in clearing the orc tribe, the Druid will use control weather to make it rain heavily. If they don't, he'll not change the weather.

Is it possible to tell if a given event will succeed by using this trick?